# The function return undefined Vuejs And Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to create tree view for categories section by using laravel + vuejs
This Tree view show in the create new category vue component to know if the new category is parent category or child from another category. the problem is that I can't get the id of the choosen category so I Forced to use jquery to get the id of input radio in checked but I can't know how to use the return value from javascript function into the creating new category vue function
Sorry if I can't explain the problem better

```
<template>
<!------------------------Add Category Modal --------------------------->
    <div v-if="showModal" @close="showModal=false;this.image.reset();" class="modal fade" id="addCategory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form method="post" class="form" @submit.prevent="saveData">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add new Category</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Category Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" v-model="name" placeholder=" Enter Category name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Category Description:</label>
                             <textarea class="form-control" v-model="description" placeholder="Category Description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Category Tags:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" v-model="tags" placeholder="Category Tags"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Category Status:</label>
                            <select v-model="status" class="form-control">
                                <option value="1" selected>Active</option>
                                <option value="0">Not-Active</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Category Department:</label>
                            <ul class="tree" v-for="cat in cats" v-html="cat" @click="itemClick">
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="image">Category image:</label>
                            <input type="file" v-on:change="onImageChange" id="image" name="image" class="form-control">
                            <br>
                            <div v-if="image">
                                <img :src="image" class="img-responsive" height="30" width="60">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ loading ? 'Saving Please Wait ....' : 'Save' }}</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>



<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            Categories:[],
            cats:[],
            id:'',
            parent_id:'',
            name:'',
            image:'',
            description:'',
            tags:'',
            status:'',
            loading: false,
            showModal:false,
            editModal:false,
            selected: [],
            selectAll: false,
            src:'/uploads/categories/',
            csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
        }
    },
    methods:{
        itemClick() {
           $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
                if(this.checked) {
                    return $(this).val();
                }
            });
        },
        getCats(){
            axios.get('/dashboard/load_cats/'+this.parent_id).then(res => {
                this.cats = res.data;
            })
        },

        saveData(){
            this.loading = true;
            let uri = '/dashboard/categories';
            if (!this.name || ! this.status) {
                this.loading = false;
                toastr.error('Category Name And Status Required');
            }
            if(this.name && this.status) {
                axios.post(uri, {
                    name: this.name,
                    image: this.image,
                    description: this.description,
                    tags: this.tags,
                    status:this.status,
                    parent_id:this.parent_id
                }).then(res => {
                    toastr.success(res.data);
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.showModal = false;
                    $(".modal-backdrop").hide();
                    this.name = '';
                    this.image = '';
                    this.description = '';
                    this.tags = '';
                    this.status = '';
                    this.parent_id = '';
                    this.getCategories();
                    this.getCats();
                }).catch(err => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    toastr.error(err.response.data.error);
                })
                console.log('This is Parent Id '+this.itemClick());
            }
        },



    },
    mounted() {
        this.getCategories();
        this.getCats();
    },
    computed:{

    }
}
```

and this the function load cats in categoriescontroller

```
function load_cats($parent_id = null){
    $categories = Category::where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->get();
    $cats = '';
    $selected = '';
    foreach ($categories as $cat){

        if($parent_id != 0){
            if($cat->id == $parent_id)
                $selected = 'selectParent';
        }
        $cats.='<li class="branch">';
        if(count($cat->category) > 0){
            $cats.= '<input type="radio" name="cat_id" class="parent" value="'.$cat->id.'"/> <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> '.$cat->name;
            $cats.= load_cats_childs($cat->category,$parent_id);
        }else{
            $cats.= '<input type="radio" name="cat_id" class="parent" value="'.$cat->id.'"/> <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> '.$cat->name;
        }
        $cats.='</li>';
    }

    return response()->json(['data'=> $cats]);
}
```

this is my first app in laravel + vuejs
thank you

Comment: Dit you even consider watching the property for a change: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Comment: Additionally, you would want do that rendering in Vue and return categories json rather than some unmanageable string concatenations.

Comment: Or, use a view. You can make a `.blade.php` file that contains your HTML, then return `view("view")->render()`